# Web API "2" template with Attribute Routing returning 404 when building

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

Steps:

```
1. Create empty project, click checkbox for Web API and Test project 
   (probably optional)
2. In WebApiConfig.cs, clear out Register contents, set to 
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
3. Create Controller:

   public class TestController
   {
       [HttpGet("test")]
       public string GetVal()
       {
             return "Testing";
       }
   }
4. Build and run project
5. Open Fiddler/Postman/etc and go to localhost:port/test -> 404
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this particular part working?

edit:

Should probably state that the server default is IIS 8.0 Express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your controller class inherits from `ApiController`.

(To be exact here: Your controller doesn't necessarily have to be derived from `ApiController`, but has to implement `IHttpController`. Most of the time that's achieved through subclassing `ApiController`, though.)

Comment: Blah. That was boneheaded of me to forget.